# Move text inside an element to its child element

Tags: jquery

I want to move a text snippet inside the `label` to be inside the `a` element. I'm not a jQuery wizard and I don't understand how to use `appendTo`, `insertBefore` etc when I can't target the textsample. I want to keep the HTML intact except the move of the text.

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="cart">
        <div class="filter">
            <label>
                <a></a>
                textsample
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">
            <label>
                <a></a>
                textsample
            </label>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry it is unclear what you want to do? what is the expected output

Comment: which element has to be moved inside which element

Comment: from `<label><a></a>textsample</label>` to `<label><a>textsample</a></label>` i suspect like this. question is does OP wants all label text to be wrapped in `a` or selected only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the `anchor`  element and use `.append()` to move the text.

```js
$(".filter label a").each(function() {
  $(this).append(this.nextSibling); //Read the text node using plain JS property
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="xart">
    <div class="filter">
      <label>
        <a href="#"></a>textsample</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
      <label>
        <a href="#"></a>textsample</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it like this.

```
var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
    return $(el).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
};

$(".filter label").each(function() {
    // retrieves the text content from the `<label>`

    var theText=$(this).text();
    // find the text content and remove it
    getTextNodesIn(this).remove();

    // add the text content back to the `<a>` tag
    $(this).find("a").html(theText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the text, then replace the content of the tags:

```js
$('.filter label').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<a>' + text + '</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="xart">
    <div class="filter">
      <label>
        <a></a>
        textsample
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
      <label>
        <a></a>
        textsample
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check out this answer in jQuery :

```
$(".filter label").each(function() {
   var Text=$(this).text();
   $(this).text("");
   $(this).append('<a>'+Text+'</a>');
});
```